# Following the tutorial on using bitmaps to make android images smaller

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I am learning how to use Bitmap to scale down images instead of having them crash the app.  I am following the developer page for android at http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html.  I have a couple of questions about the code.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
String imageType = options.outMimeType;
```

For the code above it creates a new bitmapFactory and decodes the widget.  Why use R.id.myimage over R.drawable.image?  I am assuming that R.id.myimage refers to a image view while R.drawable.image I added and it directly refers to the image I want rescaled.   Finally what does outMimeType refer too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, I'm pretty sure that's a mistake. The resource you want is indeed a drawable, referenced by `R.drawable.image`.

The `options.outMimetype` just tells you what the mimetype of the decoded resource is (a PNG, a JPEG, etc.), if that information is available.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting a run time error when running of the code from the android developer site and am trying to nail down what is going on.  So now I know that this part is correct